# Plutogrid show dialog after iconbutton pressed

Tags: flutter

how can I show an dialog widget after a click on an Iconbutton in a plutogrid cell?

This is my code in der renderer for the plutogrid cell:

```
return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Auswahl,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {}, => here I want to show a dialog widged...

                  iconSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                                 ),
              ]);
```

And here is the code for the dialog:

```
void _selectDialog() async {
       showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add Info'),
            content: setupSelectDialoagContainer(),
          );
        });
  }
```

I tried to call _selectDialog(), but I got the error:

The instance member '_selectDialog' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you faced this error, this is my code showing the same dialog as yours and it's working.

Here's the code:

```js
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({super.key});

  @override
  State<Demo> createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  void _selectDialog() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add Info'),
            // content: setupSelectDialoagContainer(),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _selectDialog();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The difference is the plutogrid, I used... Here you add the IconButton inside the renderer of a plutogrid column like...  renderer: (rendererContext) { return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Auswahl,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},

                  iconSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
             
                ),
              ]);}